# Swift: How to integrate a library?

Tags: swift

I like to integrate a [zip](https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/zipping-and-unzipping-files-in-your-swift-app-1b33a82b4b88#.y6q6ds8k9) library in my macOS application.

I created a file named **Podfile** in my project folder (next to **.xcodeproj** file).
It contains following lines (as given [here](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) - on the bottom of the page):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'Zip', '~> 0.4'
```

If I run *$ pod install* on the terminal, I am receiving this error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The dependency `Zip (~> 0.4)` is not used in any concrete target.
```

**EDIT**:
I tried it now with the *pod init* template, but got an error. So I raised a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332542/swift-error-9806-while-trying-to-integrate-a-library).

Comment: Scroll down on https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple question, and it does mean that you didn't give your research on what you are searching for. Please do your research, and then post a question here if there is any problem. Please give respect to people's time.

GitHub repo [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive#cocoapods)

CocoaPods

```
pod install SSZipArchive
```

Carthage

```
github "ZipArchive/ZipArchive"
```

Comment: @dimpiax I didn't understand what you mean by that?