# Cocoapods: Error -9806 while trying to integrate a library

Tags: cocoapods

I like to integrate a [zip](https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/zipping-and-unzipping-files-in-your-swift-app-1b33a82b4b88#.y6q6ds8k9) library in my macOS application.

I created the Podfile with *pod init* and added the pod to it:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :osx, '10.10'

target 'Test' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Test
  pod 'Zip', '~> 0.4'
end
```

But if I execute *pod install* I am getting following output on the console (tried it a few times):

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Zip (0.4.3)

[!] Error installing Zip
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip.git /var/folders/n5/4f8c27g57tn94vhb7xcd95ww0000gp/T/d20160712-26003-1l6n5lt --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.4.3

Cloning into '/var/folders/n5/4f8c27g57tn94vhb7xcd95ww0000gp/T/d20160712-26003-1l6n5lt'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing **curl with OpenSSL** *pod install* did work:

```
$ brew install --with-openssl curl
```